# How can the hashed password be decrypted?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used  SHA1 algorithm of salt technique to hash password in my site. Is there any way to decrypt the password and recover the original?

Comment: You can't do that. Hashing is a one way process.

Comment: The whole point is you do hashing if you *don't* want to be able to recover the password. You can still use it to *verify* a password by repeating the hashing process with the text to check and comparing the output.

Comment: You cannot "decrypt" a hashed password. But SHA1 is *relatively* vurnerable to brute force attacks. As described [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html), you might want to switch to [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pbkdf2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hashing* is not encrypting/de-crypting.

When we hash something, we derive a number (or sequence of characters) from a particular set of bytes so that the same set of bytes produces the same hash code.  This is a one-way process and we cannot go back.

With encryption we use algorithms that turn a sequence of bytes in to something that no longer resembles the original content, *however* if we know how it was encrypted, we can decrypt it.

Hashing is useful when we don't need to know what the original content was.  A good example of this is passwords (that you mention in your post).  We store the *hashed* version (with salt) in the database.  When the user comes to log in again, we hash the password they entered.  If the two hashes match, then it must be the same password.  But at no point have we revealed what the password actually *is* and it is not stored in plain-text within the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that, SHA1 is a hashing algorithm:
It always go from plain text to a hash signature.

If you want to be able to go both ways you need to look at symmetric algorithms.

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx